# Showing that $\int_0^{\infty}\sin{(ax)}dx\int_{a}^{\infty}f(y)e^{-xy}dy=a\int_a^{\infty}\frac{f(y)}{a^2+y^2}dy$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Suppose that $\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|dx<\infty, \int_{1}^{\infty}|f(x)|x^{-2}dx<\infty$. Then $\int_0^{\infty}\sin{(ax)}dx\int_{a}^{\infty}f(y)e^{-xy}dy=a\int_a^{\infty}\frac{f(y)}{a^2+y^2}dy$.

I am having trouble applying Fubini's theorem appropriately to prove above statement. Honestly, I don't know how to start. Any demonstrations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Do Fubini and then twice integration by parts on the inner integral.